# If $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$, what is $\sum n^3 a_n z^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Problem:** If $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$, what is $\sum n^3 a_n z^n$?

**Attempt:**

1. First we note that

   $$
   f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n z^{(n-1)}
   $$

   so that

   $$
   z f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n z^n
   $$
2. From this we can see that multiplying $\sum a_n z^n$ by $z$ and taking the derivative three times in a row will yield us the desired result of $\sum_{n=3}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n$.  More specifically, we have that

   $$
   z[z[zf']']'(z) = \sum_{n=3}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n
   $$

   so that

   $$ 
   \left( 0^3 a_0 + 1^3 a_1 z + 2^3 a_2 z^2 \right) + z[z[zf']']'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3 a_n z^n
   $$

**Question:** Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you *sure* that should be $n=3$ as the starting index? You have some typos/errors in your last equation too: $n$'s on the left hand side don't make sense, and I think you wrote the right hand side wrong too.

Comment: I think that should be an $n=3$, no?  And I fixed the bad equation -- thanks for the comment (as originally written it was indeed nonsense).

Comment: In the first step, you changed from $n=0$ to $n=1$ as the lower bound; this is correct, as the $n=0$ term is $0a_0z^{0-1}=0$, but it's also unnecessary. And then you falsely generalized to increasing the lower bound by $1$ at every step, which is definitely incorrect (try your formula when $f(z)=z^2$ for example to see). The lower bound should remain $n=0$ throughout. (And otherwise, I think the triple derivative-times-$z$ formula is the best you can do.)